# Orthogonality of $c(t)_{c(t)}$ and a tangent vector

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Some set-up from Spivak's textbook:

> Given a differentiable map $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$,  define $f_\ast:
>  \mathbb R_p^n\to \mathbb R_{f(p)}^m$ by
>   $$f_\ast(v_p)=(Df(p)(v))_{f(p)}.$$
>   Note that the notation $v_p$ stands for the vector $v$ at $p$ (so the RHS is a vector at $f(p)$).
>
> Let $c$ be a differentiable curve in $\mathbb R^n$, i.e., a differentiable function $c:[0,1]\to \mathbb R^n$. Define the ***tangent vector*** $v$ of $c$ at $t$ as $c_\ast((e_1)_t)=((c^1)'(t),\dots,(c^n)'(t))_{c(t)}$.

Let $c$ be a curve as above with $|c(t)|=1$ for all $t$. Show that $c(t)_{c(t)}$ and the tangent vector to $c$ at $t$ are perpendicular.

First of all, what does $c(t)_{c(t)}$  stand for? The subscript alludes to the fact that $c(t)$ is considered as a tangent vector at $c(t)$, which makes no sense since $c(t)$ is a curve, not a vector. On the other hand, perpendicularity (I assume w.r.t. the standard dot product) is defined only for vectors. So I have no idea what this problem is asking and how to solve it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which of Spivak's textbook do you find this problem?

Comment: @edm "Calculus on Manifolds"

Comment: Please, tell exactly where you find this problem (tell the page number).

Comment: @edm This is Problem 4-16 p. 96.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $c(t) \in \Bbb R^n$, so $c(t)_{c(t)}$ denotes the vector $c(t)$ starting in the point $c(t)$. Then if $|c(t)|=1$ for all $t$, square that and differentiate to get $c(t) \cdot c'(t) = 0$, and this $\cdot$ is the product in the vector space $\Bbb R^n$. Now, by definition of the inner product $\ast$ in $T_{c(t)}\Bbb R^n = \Bbb R^n_{c(t)}$, we have $$c(t)_{c(t)} \ast c'(t)_{c(t)} = c(t)\cdot c'(t) = 0,$$as wanted.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the part with "the product in the vector space $\mathbb R^n$". The equality $|c(t)|^2=1$ is precisely $c(t)\cdot c(t)=1$ where the LHS is the inner product of $c(t)$ with itself. How can you differentiate inner products? Or you mean that one can write $c(t)=(c_1(t),\dots, c_n(t))$, and then $|c(t)|^2=1$ is just $c_1(t)^2+\dots+c_n(t)^2=1$, and by differentiating this one gets $c_1(t)c_1'(t)+\dots+c_n(t)c_n'(t)=0$ or equivalently $c(t)\cdot c'(t) =0$ where the LHS is the dot product? If so, everything seems to be clear.

Comment: You learnt total derivatives from maps $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^k$ and things of the sort previously in the book, right? In particular, if $B\colon \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^k \to \Bbb R^m$ is bilinear, you have that $B$ is differentiable and $$DB(x,y)(h,k) = B(x,k) + B(h,y).$$The inner product in $\Bbb R^n$ is bilinear, and so is the curve $c$. Since $c(t) \cdot c(t) =1$ holds in an open interval, you can differentiate that to conclude that $c(t)\cdot c'(t) = 0$. You use that and the definition of the inner product in the tangent spaces. All the structure in $\Bbb R^n_p$ comes from $\Bbb R^n$ (...)

Comment: (...) as in $v_p + w_p \doteq (v+w)_p$, $\lambda v_p \doteq (\lambda v)_p$, $\langle v_p, w_p \rangle_p \doteq  v\cdot w$, etc.. Maybe I shouldn't use $\ast$ for the inner product there. I guess that $$\langle c(t)_{c(t)}, c'(t)_{c(t)}\rangle_{c(t)} = c(t) \cdot c'(t) = 0$$is better.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. But I'm still curious whether the argument I described works. (It avoids "differentiating inner products" explicitly.)

Comment: Your argument is exactly the same one I gave. I just didn't wrote the components $c_i$ explicitly (and you don't need to, if you know how to differentiate bilinear maps).